# .net core web API not getting authenticated even after generating bearer token from Azure AD using AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-authentication

I am developing a .net core Web API and I am trying to authenticate it using AZURE AD authentication.
I am following below configurations.:

1.In Startup.cs I have added authentication scheme as :AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
              .AddAzureADBearer(options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });
```

2.In configure method of startup.cs I have added:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

3.In app.settings.json I have added following properties:

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "<MY client ID>",
    "TenantId": "<My Tenant ID>",
    "Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<My Tenant ID>/v2.0",
    "Domain": "<My Domain>",
    "ConfigView": "MVC",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "<My Client Secret>"
  }
```

4. I have added Authorize attribute on top of my controller
5. I have generated my Bearer token using following code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            IRestResponse ARMtokenResponse = obj.GetARMAuthToken();
            dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ARMtokenResponse.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(response["access_token"].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private IRestResponse GetARMAuthToken()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MY TENANT ID>/oauth2/token"); //tenantid
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "<My Client ID>");
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", "<MY CLIENT SECRET>");
            request.AddParameter("resource", "https://management.azure.com/");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
```

6. Further I am using this token generated, in postman/console app for calling the API but getting error in response header: **Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"**

Please help me in this. I am stuck here

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your codes :

1. You should acquire access token for web api , not acquiring access token for Azure Rest API (https://management.azure.com/) , your web api can't validate Azure Rest API's access token .
2. When acquiring token you are using Azure AD V1.0 endpoint , but when validating token you are using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint (`Issuer`) .

For Azure AD V1.0 , you can refer to code sample : [Call a web API in an ASP.NET Core web app using Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master/).

For Azure AD V2.0 , you can refer to code samples : [Enable your Web Apps to sign-in users and call APIs with the Microsoft identity platform for developers](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) , and follow the `4-WebApp-your-API` scenario .

Comment: Thank you for answer Nan Yu, But as I am somewhat new to azure AD authentication will you please explain me what changes I have to make , so it will work?

Comment: You should acquire token for accessing your web api , not Azure Rest API , code samples are provided above .